# Retrieving Movie Ratings from Websites/Blogs for Android App

Tags: android

Is it possible to retrieve movie/songs rating from different website or a blog and show it in android application as to which blog or website has given how much rating to a movie/song and show it in one place.

P.S: I am beginner at android application development and got this idea to make a app which could fetch ratings for a particular songs or movie . So if it is possible it will be great if you give me a little headstart as to how will it will be done .

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Stackoverflow is meant for these type of questions. Please start with reading the dev guide : http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like a external server or database that does crawling work for you.

You would need something like a list of websites/blogs you get your ratings from and you would need to write something like a crawling script for each website. That means downloading the HTML-file of the site and parse it for your information. This data must be stored in your database or the server must do this dynamically.

Now your device connects to the database/server to get the analysated data. If you let your device do the whole parsing-work, it would kill the net-traffic and would take ages to load.